# How can I maximize the value of carried gems with a number and weight restriction?

Tags: algorithm, knapsack-problem

Let's say you have 100 precious gems, each has a weight from 0 to 100, and the value of each could be any positive number. You can only carry 5 of them, and the combined weight can't exceed 30.

How can I pick the gems to carry that will result in the maximum value?

Currently, I have an analogous situation in my project and I'm solving it via brute force. Is there a quicker way?

Comment: Can you have gems with a weight > 30? What do you do with those?

Comment: @pandaadb Do not consider them. Moreover in such situations most of the time this will not happen.

Comment: Naive approach: Couldn't you just sort them, so the heaviest are stored first in your list, then navigate from left to right and add items until you either reach 5 or exceed the weight?

Comment: You were missing the right keyword to google. This is (a variant of) the **knapsack problem**. Lots of different ways to tackle it. Arguably the easiest is dynamic programming. That is not tractable though and there are approximate methods for large number of "gems".

Comment: More precisely, it is a 2-dimensional knapsack problem. Indeed, you have constraints both in term of weight and number of items. It is harder to solve. You can apply solutions to the common variant where there are weight and volume constraints - it's just that all gems have the same volume (1) and the maximum volume is 5.

Answer (score 3):

hi this is a very common algorithmic challenge known as the knapsack problem, best solved by dynamic programming:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Answer (score 1):

Refer to 0-1 knapsack problem. [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)

Comment: Whoever that is, why downvote? The question is a variation of the problem.

Comment: This is little more than a link. It's usually best to include sufficient details about the algorithm **in the answer itself** so any readers can figure out how to solve the given problem based on that alone (without visiting any other page), and including links for **more** details. Yes, the other answer also has this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the naive approach of sorting the gems and choosing the heaviest first won't work is because the heaviest gems may not have the greatest value.  That is why the knapsack algorithm is needed:  it chooses the maximum value that results from either choosing a gem or not choosing a gem.  The next gem or gems may have a greater value than the current gem.  The recursive knapsack solution lools like:

```
def knapsack(weights, values, capacity, m, count):
    # if no more gems to examine or already chosen 5 gems
    if (m == 0 or count == 5):
        return 0

    # If the gem weight is greater than the capacity
    # try the next gem
    if (weights[m-1] > capacity):  
        return knapsack(weights, values, capacity, m-1, count)  

    # Return the maximum value that results from either choosing the gem
    # or not choosing the gem.
    return max(values[m-1] + knapsack(weights, values, capacity-weights[m-1], m-1, count+1),
               knapsack(weights, values, capacity, m-1, count)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this knapsack problem with either a recursive way or an iterative way, below is a recursive bottom-up method using memoizatoin which I think is the best way to solve this problem.

```
# w is weights list, v is values list, aw is the total available weight
# i is the number of items (last index of the list)
# m is a dictionary for memoization

def knapsack(w, v, aw, i, m):
    try:
        return m[(i, aw)]
    except KeyError:
        if i == 0:
            if w[i] > aw:
                m[(i, aw)] = 0
                return 0
            else:
                m[(i, aw)] = v[i]
                return v[i]
        without = knapsack(w, v, aw, i-1, m)
        if (w[i] > aw):
            m[(i, aw)] = without 
            return without
        else:
            withi = v[i] + knapsack(w, v, aw-w[i], i-1, m)
            result = withi if withi > without else without
            m[(i, aw)] = result
            return result
```